# Ie11 gives cors error on file even if html files are in the same directory

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, xmlhttprequest, internet-explorer-11, same-origin-policy

As the title, ie11 gives cors error for file protocol, even if files are in the same directory.

```
../
-test.html
-frame.html
-test.json
```

I cant get the frame html with iframe and cant send xmlhttprequest to test.json. Gives cors error for both of them

How do I get away with this ?

Comment: For security reasons, browsers consider every `file://` URL to be distinct for CORS purposes. It's to protect against attacks involving things like `README.htlml` files on shady installation media.

Comment: If you're trying to use XHR, you'll need a local server anyway. Once you have "real" URLs the problem will go away.

Comment: Is it just `IE`? `Chrome` should also throw the same error.

Comment: @nickzoum I think Chrome has a startup option that can be used to override this.

Comment: In my opinion simplest solution (if you are using windows) is to place the files you want to get in your iis. Then you can just do `localhost/nameofsite/test.json`

Comment: @nick zoum well, I cant setup http server because of some reason. I must view them with file protocol

Comment: IE has some restrictions while accessing the web page using file protocol. Try to go to tools-> Internet options->security-> custom level-> Access data sources across domains and Enable it. i.postimg.cc/fR6vyCMZ/144.png If issue persist than you should try to host the site on web server to test your JSON.